# Unable to create a datasource. Datasource fails to 'test successfully' for SSRS

Tags: ssrs

I imported an SSRS 2008 Datasource to SSRS 2012 using RS Scripter tool.

The DB connection is the same for the SSRS 2008 and SSRS 2012 data source created.

I can 'test successfully' the login/pw for SSRS 2008 datasource, but  'fail' with SSRS 2012.

The login has permissions and exists (They are the same for both SSRS datasources)

Any suggestions on how to trouble shoot this? 
I asked Server Admins if there are firewall issues, they stated there shouldn't be any.
I was able to ping both hosts (though maybe that doesn't mean much sometimes)

Comment: You should  be  able  to  manually  create another data source on your 2012 instance. Just give it a different name. My hunch is that your script doesn't have the credentials correct.

Comment: Does your ssrs  server  have ssms? And can you log into it with remote  desktop?  If so you could connect to your source db from the server using ssms and your  data source credentials to rule out firewall  issues.

Comment: Hi @peter.  Thanks for Suggestion, I tried manually created another datasource  but still get error msg:   'Log on failed. Ensure the user name and password are correct.'   when attempting to 'test connection'   On older SSRS 2008 server I can create a new datasource using same login/pw but 'Succeeds'  so I can confirm login/pw ok.    Also  on new server I can use my own domain login/pw 'Succeeds'  this validates no firewall issues.

Comment: Can you change the password for user data source just to rule it out? Does  the password use unusual characters?

Comment: Can you confirm you're  connecting from 2008 SSRS  instance to remote  db. And also from 2012 SSRS instance to same  remote db? You're  talking about 3 servers.

Comment: Peter thanks for hanging in there and helping. I made a discovery it was a windows AD issue specific with that service account. I think i should post the answer below

Comment: Wow. Good find :) glad you have resolved it.

Answer (score 2):

The issue had to due with Windows GPO it was unknown to me at the time
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326317%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: +1 for Normoe. In my organisation we lock the Allow Log On Locally setting down, so the account I was using had to be added to the AD group allowed to log on locally. 30 seconds later all was well.